# Combine datasets

Tags: r

I'm supposed to combine all four datasets from https://www.drroyspencer.com/latest-global-temperatures/ into one dataframe. I've tried to merge it without luck. Any help?

What I've tried so far.

```r
# Lower troposphere data.
lower_trop <- fread("https://www.nsstc.uah.edu/data/msu/v6.0/tlt/uahncdc_lt_6.0.txt", sep = " ")

# Mid-Troposphere data.
mid_trop <- fread("https://www.nsstc.uah.edu/data/msu/v6.0/tmt/uahncdc_mt_6.0.txt", sep = " ")

# Tropopause data.
trop <- fread("https://www.nsstc.uah.edu/data/msu/v6.0/ttp/uahncdc_tp_6.0.txt", sep = " ")

# Lower Stratosphere data.
lower_strat <- fread("https://www.nsstc.uah.edu/data/msu/v6.0/tls/uahncdc_ls_6.0.txt" , sep = " ")

# 
lower_trop1 <- lower_trop[-c(518)]
mid_trop1 <- Mid_trop[-c(518)]
trop1 <- trop[-c(518)]
lower_strat1 <- lower_strat[-c(518)]

# 
lower_trop <- as.data.frame(apply(lower_trop1, 2, as.numeric))
mid_trop <- as.data.frame(apply(mid_trop1, 2, as.numeric))
trop_paus <- as.data.frame((apply(trop1, 2, as.numeric)))
lower_strat <- as.data.frame(apply(lower_strat1, 2, as.numeric))

all<- rbind(lower_trop,mid_trop,trop_paus,lower_strat)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please read and incorporate elements from [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Especially the aspects of using `dput()` for the input and then an explicit example of your expected dataset?

Comment: `Mid_trop` or `Mid_trop`?

Answer (score 1):

1. **Don't ignore warnings.** Your `fread` calls are warning

   ```r
   lower_trop <- fread("https://www.nsstc.uah.edu/data/msu/v6.0/tlt/uahncdc_lt_6.0.txt", sep = " ")
   #  [100%] Downloaded 89265 bytes...
   # Warning in fread("https://www.nsstc.uah.edu/data/msu/v6.0/tlt/uahncdc_lt_6.0.txt",  :
   #   Stopped early on line 520. Expected 29 fields but found 0. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line: <<Trend    0.14  0.18  0.12  0.16  0.19  0.14  0.11  0.16  0.10  0.12  0.16  0.11  0.18  0.21  0.17  0.10  0.15  0.09  0.25  0.23  0.27  0.01  0.09 -0.02  0.18  0.18  0.18>>
   ```

   This is because those files have trailing material that are not "proper CSV" (as far as R cares, that is):

   ```
    Year Mo Globe  Land Ocean   NH   Land Ocean   SH   Land Ocean Trpcs  Land Ocean NoExt  Land Ocean SoExt  Land Ocean NoPol  Land Ocean SoPol  Land Ocean USA48 USA49  AUST
    1978 12 -0.48 -0.51 -0.47 -0.44 -0.46 -0.42 -0.52 -0.62 -0.50 -0.60 -0.62 -0.59 -0.37 -0.44 -0.30 -0.46 -0.55 -0.45 -0.39 -0.68 -0.06 -0.45 -0.38 -0.49 -1.29 -1.15 -1.29
    1979  1 -0.47 -0.64 -0.41 -0.64 -0.86 -0.50 -0.31 -0.13 -0.34 -0.47 -0.54 -0.45 -0.73 -0.93 -0.55 -0.23  0.12 -0.29 -0.46 -0.95  0.10 -0.16 -0.15 -0.16 -3.22 -2.42  0.92
   ...snip...
    2021 11  0.08  0.22  0.03  0.11  0.32 -0.02  0.06 -0.00  0.07  0.14  0.35  0.08  0.09  0.31 -0.10  0.02 -0.24  0.06 -0.43 -0.19 -0.70 -0.72 -0.67 -0.75  0.50 -0.06 -0.29
    2021 12  0.21  0.17  0.22  0.27  0.19  0.32  0.15  0.12  0.15  0.03  0.30 -0.04  0.40  0.19  0.59  0.20 -0.07  0.25  0.01 -0.25  0.31 -0.42 -0.24 -0.51  1.63  1.42 -0.06
    Year Mo Globe  Land Ocean   NH   Land Ocean   SH   Land Ocean Trpcs  Land Ocean NoExt  Land Ocean SoExt  Land Ocean NoPol  Land Ocean SoPol  Land Ocean USA48 USA49  AUST

    Trend    0.14  0.18  0.12  0.16  0.19  0.14  0.11  0.16  0.10  0.12  0.16  0.11  0.18  0.21  0.17  0.10  0.15  0.09  0.25  0.23  0.27  0.01  0.09 -0.02  0.18  0.18  0.18

     NOTE:  Version 6.0 as of April 2015
     NOTE:  New Reference for annual cycle 1991-2020
     NOTE:  Version 5.6 as of Jun 2013
     NOTE:  3/13 More accurate grid weighting for USA48
     NOTE:  3/13 Alaska added in USA49, Australia added

     GL 90S-90N, NH 0-90N, SH 90S-0, TRPCS 20S-20N
     NoExt 20N-90N, SoExt 90S-20S, NoPol 60N-90N, SoPol 90S-60S
   ```

   There is no easy way to just "ignore" those lines, so I suggest you be very clear about it: state that *that* warning is expected and not a concern here. Your future self (and colleagues) will thank you. You can use this to silence *just that warning* (and allow `fread` to continue normal operations):

   ```r
   lower_trop <- withCallingHandlers(
       fread("https://www.nsstc.uah.edu/data/msu/v6.0/tlt/uahncdc_lt_6.0.txt", sep = " "),
       warning = function(w) {
         if (grepl("Stopped early on line", as.character(w))) 
           invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
       })
   ```
2. **R dislikes non-unique column names.** I don't know anything about the data, but it appears that `Land` and `Ocean` are grouped by the preceding columns `Globe`, `NH`, `SH`, etc. Let's  rename them to ensure they are unique and unambiguous (not just numbers):

   ```r
   lands <- which(names(lower_trop1) == "Land")
   names(lower_trop1)[lands] <- paste0(names(lower_trop1)[lands-1], "_", names(lower_trop1)[lands])
   names(lower_trop1)[lands+1] <- paste0(names(lower_trop1)[lands-1], "_", names(lower_trop1)[lands+1])
   head(lower_trop1)
   #      Year     Mo  Globe Globe_Land Globe_Ocean     NH NH_Land NH_Ocean     SH SH_Land SH_Ocean  Trpcs Trpcs_Land
   #    <char> <char> <char>     <char>      <char> <char>  <char>   <char> <char>  <char>   <char> <char>     <char>
   # 1:   1978     12  -0.48      -0.51       -0.47  -0.44   -0.46    -0.42  -0.52   -0.62    -0.50  -0.60      -0.62
   # 2:   1979      1  -0.47      -0.64       -0.41  -0.64   -0.86    -0.50  -0.31   -0.13    -0.34  -0.47      -0.54
   # 3:   1979      2  -0.43      -0.56       -0.39  -0.47   -0.57    -0.41  -0.39   -0.53    -0.37  -0.36      -0.25
   # 4:   1979      3  -0.38      -0.51       -0.33  -0.46   -0.51    -0.44  -0.30   -0.53    -0.26  -0.36      -0.43
   # 5:   1979      4  -0.40      -0.57       -0.34  -0.47   -0.62    -0.37  -0.34   -0.46    -0.31  -0.35      -0.37
   # 6:   1979      5  -0.40      -0.56       -0.33  -0.52   -0.54    -0.52  -0.27   -0.62    -0.19  -0.46      -0.55
   # 16 variables not shown: [Trpcs_Ocean <char>, NoExt <char>, NoExt_Land <char>, NoExt_Ocean <char>, SoExt <char>, SoExt_Land <char>, SoExt_Ocean <char>, NoPol <char>, NoPol_Land <char>, NoPol_Ocean <char>, ...]
   ```
3. (Almost) **Never use `apply` on a `data.frame`.** Okay, *almost never*, there are legitimate times to do it. However, by default, `apply` is going to return a `matrix` when you really need it to remain a `data.frame` (or at least `list`-like). Use `lapply` instead:

   ```r
   lower_trop1[] <- lapply(lower_trop1, as.numeric)
   ```

   Two tricks to know about this and how it works with frames:

   1. A `data.frame` is just a glorified `list` with some added conditions: all elements should be named uniquely; all elements (typically) must be the same length; it may have row-names, some tools use/honor/keep them, some tools (`dplyr`) ignore or actively remove them. Oh, and the `class` is slightly different. But most things that work on `list`s work just as well on `data.frame`s, column-wise.
   2. Even though we're working on columns of a frame, in one sense we're just working on elements of a `list`, *and we want it to stay `list`-like*, so we should be using `lapply`.
   3. Unfortunately, `lapply` is going to return a `list` not a `data.frame`, so the reassignment into `lower_trop1[] <- ...` says to replace the contents of `lower_trop1` without changing its class. There is likely more that can be said here, but know that `frame[] <- lapply(frame, ...)` preserves the `data.frame` properties we need while allowing very simple `lapply`-operations.

From here, `rbind` should work as intended.

FYI, you can combine your middle two steps with:

```r
lower_trop1 <- lower_trop[-518,][, lapply(.SD, as.numeric)]
```

though you still need to do the renaming for unique columns names.

Comment: Thank you so much for the long and comprehensive answer. I will try this now!!

Comment: Hey @r2evans, its a bit weird im getting an error on "Stage" 2 in your comment. error is as following: 
'> names(lower_trop)[lands] <- paste0(names(lower_trop)[lands-1], "_", names(lower_trop)[lands])
Error in paste0(names(lower_trop)[lands - 1], "_", names(lower_trop)[lands]) : 
  object 'lands' not found
> names(lower_trop)[lands+1] <- paste0(names(lower_trop)[lands-1], "_", names(lower_trop)[lands+1])
Error in paste0(names(lower_trop)[lands - 1], "_", names(lower_trop)[lands +  : 
  object 'lands' not found'

Do u see what im doing wrong?

Comment: My bad, editing ... it's `lands <- which(names(lower_trop1) == "Land")`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want some sort of join (so joining the columns from the 4 datasets). Here some information on the different join options in R: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate-joins.html

Now in your case, you have the `Year` and the `Mo` columns that appear in your different datasets. So you could join the datasets by these columns. Here an example of a left join (just for the first two dataframes):

First, make sure that you have unique column names in each single dataframe (you do currently not have unique names, so this step is necessary):

```
names(lower_trop) <- make.unique(names(lower_trop), sep="_")
names(mid_trop) <- make.unique(names(lower_trop), sep="_")
```

Then you join these with a left join (so you keep all the rows from the left dataset):

```
new_df <- left_join(lower_trop, mid_trop, by = c("Year", "Mo"), suffix = c(".lower_trop", ".mid_trop"))
```

Comment: Thank you @Ane! This seems to be working

Comment: That's great! Although this is not the cleanest way to solve the issue (given all the warnings and the non-unique column names) - I think you should take the comments made by @r2evans seriously. In addition, it seemed like what you wanted to do initially was rbind (so add the rows). I suggested a join (so join the columns). Maybe you should think again about what you want to achieve and choose the appropriate method accordingly :) Good luck!